# Does Java groupingBy collector preserve list order?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Consider a list `List<People>` where the elements are sorted in ascending order of `People.getAge()`. If we group this list using `Collectors.groupingBy(People::getCity)`, would the resultant lists for each of the groups/cities remain sorted on age?

In practice, it does seem to preserve the order. I'm looking for a guarantee.

The Javadoc for the method says:

> If preservation of the order in which elements appear in the resulting Map collector is not required, using groupingByConcurrent(Function) may offer better parallel performance

I'm not sure if this refers to the order of items on list.

Comment: Your Javadoc quote states it quite obviously. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: @FrankPuffer: By Map collector, does it refer to the toList collector used to build the Map elements?

Comment: @FrankPuffer: It's true the quote above *suggests* that `groupingBy` preserves the order, but sadly [`Collectors.groupingBy`'s JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) doesn't say anything about doing that. Which sucks, because while we can look at the OpenJDK implementation or do empirical tests, all they tell us is what the implementation currently does, not what the contract is. So hopefully it's clarified *somewhere* in the JDK API docs.

Comment: @FrankPuffer The quoted part doesn't, really. It only talks about the case where preservation is not required, nothing the case when preservation is required ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, @Mifeet: From a strictly logical point of view you are right. But if preservation of order would not be guaranteed by `groupingBy`, the quoted sentence would not make sense. (I would not expect meaningless statements in the JavaDoc of a standard package.)

Comment: The accumulator itself is called in a way that preserves order, as per [`java.util.stream.Collector` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html), regardless of whether the stream is sequential or parallel.  Combined with what @FrankPuffer also mentioned about `groupingByConcurrent()`, any implementation that doesn't preserve order would be doing so by going way out of its way.  I think that makes it a pretty good guarantee.

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Fundamentally, the JavaDoc for `Collectors.groupingBy` doesn't say it preserves order, so it's not part of the contract. *Probably* an omission in the JavaDoc (not, by far, the only one), but contract assumptions are rich breeding grounds for bugs.

Comment: The overload that accepts a downstream collector makes it much clearer: *If preservation of the order in which elements are presented to the downstream collector is not required, using `groupingByConcurrent(Function, Collector)` may offer better parallel performance.* See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39173507/1553851) for related discussion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key to understanding the contract is where it says "the order in which elements **appear**". It talks about whether they arrive in order, which implies whether they are passed in to the key extractor `Function` and to any downstream collector in order; it doesn't say anything about whether the order will be preserved in any resulting accumulation; in fact the current implementation of `groupingBy` uses a `HashMap` which does not preserve the key order.

You ask if it refers to the order of items on the list. If you are referring to the List that the Stream was created from, a Stream created on a List does start out ordered, but some stream operations change the order or make it unordered, so the ordering it refers to refers to the resulting order after pipeline operations are done IF the stream remains ordered.  If stream operations make the stream unordered, the order in which elements appears at the collector is not an issue any longer.

If you are referring to the order of items in the List the grouped items are collected to, yes, it does, because the "order in which the elements appear" is the order in which the elements are processed. The same holds true when grouping to a downstream collector; if the Stream is still ordered, and you group to a downstream collector that preserves order, this will preserve that order, while the Concurrent version may not.

Comment: The quoted Javadoc is "If preservation of the order in which elements appear in the **resulting** Map...".  To be precise, it only said the order in **result** is preserved, for which it can be interpreted as: Given same input, no matter how many times you process it, the result ordering is the same.  For which, even the ordering in **incoming** stream is not preserved, as long as the result is consistent, it still fulfill what the Javadoc said.  (I also believe the original intention of the Javadoc is to say ordering is preserved corresponding to input.  However it is written w/ ambiguities)

Comment: Although technically ambiguous, "preservation of order" in this context probably refers to preserving the input order in the output. "preserves order" is a common phrase used to describe this exact thing.