# Java Collectors.groupingBy()---is List ordered?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

For the `Collectors.groupingBy()` that returns `Map<K,List<T>>` is it implied that the `List<T>` is in order that the stream is evaluated?

I see no explicit description of the ordering of the list, whereas the concurrent version explicitly states no ordering. If it weren't ordered somehow, I'd expect it to be a Collection though, and I don't see what other ordering it could possibly be, other than order received.

I'm hoping it's guaranteed that the last value in each list is the last value received for that group.

Comment: Short answer: if you have an ordered stream (i.e., your source is a List, array, Iterator, etc) and you don't use an unordered collector (like the concurrent collectors), yes; elements will appear as if sequentially presented to the collector in encounter order.  Note that this sometimes has a cost, and you don't care about this stability guarantee, in which case you could shed the order by including `unordered()` in your stream.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: so when I consider only collectors explicitly documented as “unordered”, even `summarizingInt` is not unordered? Is there a reason for that? And what about `groupingBy(func, toSet())`? I known, it is still ordered, due to the way, it is currently implemented, but do we have to keep the contract that way, forever forbidding implementation to recognized the order independence?

Comment: @Holger The Stream API has a strong (some would say too strong) committment to stability.  (Consider the order-preserving behavior of `sorted()` and `distinct()`, which some find excessive.)  So discarding ordering is something that must be documented, otherwise you're stuck preserving it.  You might ask "why isn't order preservation always documented?"  But think about the alternative: if `map()` and `toList()` didn't preserve order, that would be obviously broken.  (Example: `strings.stream().map(String::length).collect(toList())`.)  So we specify the permitted deviations instead.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: I got that one. My remaining question is why the documentation of `summarizingInt` does not allow its implementation to be unordered. Thinking about it, that must be an oversight, especially for `summarizingDouble` as it’s backed by `DoubleSummaryStatistics` which [explicitly denies ordering guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html#getSum--)…

Comment: @Holger As always, floating point arithmetic will defy classification, because it is not associative, which is the key assumption needed for parallelism.  The `summingDouble()` method does have a note to this effect; `summarizingDouble` probably should too.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The documentation for [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) says:

> **Implementation Requirements:**
>
> This produces a result similar to:
>
> ```
> groupingBy(classifier, toList());
> ```

The documentation for [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) says:

> **Returns:**
>
> a `Collector` which collects all the input elements into a `List`, in encounter order

So, to answer your question, as long as your stream has a defined [*encounter order*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering), you're guaranteed to get ordered lists.

---

EDIT: As @Holger points out, `groupingBy()` would also have to respect encounter order to preserve `toList()`'s ordering constraint. The fact that it does is strongly implied in this note:

> **Implementation Note:**
>
> ...If preservation of the order in which elements are presented to the downstream collector is not required, using `groupingByConcurrent(Function, Collector)` may offer better parallel performance.

Answer (score 5):

I did a real test, I init a `ArrayList<TimeBased>` with this order:

```
{"1", "2019-03-22 10:20:03", "1"},
{"2", "2019-03-22 10:30:03", "2"},
{"2", "2019-03-22 11:20:03", "3"},
{"1", "2019-03-22 11:20:15", "4"},
{"3", "2019-03-22 11:35:03", "5"},
{"2", "2019-03-22 12:20:03", "6"}
```

and groupingBy first and second column, but the result was:

```
id  birth                        number
1   Fri Mar 22 10:20:03 CST 2019 1
1   Fri Mar 22 11:20:15 CST 2019 4
2   Fri Mar 22 12:20:03 CST 2019 6
2   Fri Mar 22 11:20:03 CST 2019 3
2   Fri Mar 22 10:30:03 CST 2019 2
3   Fri Mar 22 11:35:03 CST 2019 5
```

so you see, the order is unexpected(date column order confused).

and after i do this(add LinkedList::new):

```
Map<Integer, Map<Date, List<TimeBased>>> grouped =
                timeBasedBeans.stream().collect(groupingBy(TimeBased::getId, groupingBy(TimeBased::getPeriod,
                        LinkedHashMap::new, toList())));
```

then the order is right:

```
id  birth                        number
1   Fri Mar 22 10:20:03 CST 2019 1
1   Fri Mar 22 11:20:15 CST 2019 4
2   Fri Mar 22 10:30:03 CST 2019 2
2   Fri Mar 22 11:20:03 CST 2019 3
2   Fri Mar 22 12:20:03 CST 2019 6
3   Fri Mar 22 11:35:03 CST 2019 5
```

Comment: Your example puts a Map into a Map. The default implementation uses a HashMap, which is unordered. The original question was about the order of the List when using the groupingBy() overload that produces a list.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this guarantee is not stated clearly.

However, the resulting `Collector` currently does not have the `UNORDERED` characteristic, so in fact, the resulting `List` is ordered.

The remaining question is, because there is no API contract disallowing it, could a future version (or an alternative implementation) add that characteristic and produce unordered lists? In practice, both OpenJDK and Oracle have been extremely unwilling to introduce such breaking changes even when there is strong justification for it.

Here, there is little justification to make such a change; I think it's safe to rely on this behavior.