# How to create List<T> to Map<String, T> instead of Map<String, List<T>>?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I encountered with the case when I need to convert `List<Book>` to `Map<String, Book>` and the only solutions I can find is how to do `Map<String, List<Book>>`.

The class itself looks the following way (I ommitted getters/setters and constructors):

```
public class Book {
    private String asin;
    private String author;
    private String title;
}
```

I want to map all books by certain unique keys, so probability of duplication is either neglectable or `0`.

I tried to do it this way:

```
    Map<String, Book> booksByAsinAndTitle = books.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((book) -> book.getAsin() + "||" + book.getTitle()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue().get(0)));
```

It works but it looks ugly, hardly readable and not very nice to have in the codebase because it may confuse my colleagues. Is there any better way `java 8` way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Book> booksByAsinAndTitle = 
    books.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.getAsin() + "||" + b.getTitle(),
                                   Function.identity()));
```

If the key according to which you are grouping is unique, there's no reason to use `groupingBy`.

If your key may not be unique, and you still want the `Map` to contain the first value matching a given key, add a merge function:

```
Map<String, Book> booksByAsinAndTitle = 
    books.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.getAsin() + "||" + b.getTitle(),
                                   Function.identity()),
                                   (a,b) -> a);
```

Comment: Will it be any difference if my key will not be unique and I will decide to take the first element?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi you'll have to add a merge function in that case

Comment: Well, I was thinking about it while posting my answer as well. Would `(a,b) -> a` guarantee `.get(0)`?

Comment: @nullpointer well, I think it's more correct than .get(0), since groupingBy says nothing about the order of the elements in the List of a given group. .get(0) may or may not return the first Book (according to the order of the original List) that matches a given key.

Comment: @Eran Well seemingly, `groupingBy` preserves order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172981/java-collectors-groupingby-is-list-ordered

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to group your books if you are sure that the keys are unique.

```
Map<String, Book> booksByAsinAndTitle = books.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(book -> book.getAsin() + "||" + book.getTitle(), x -> x));
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler representation of the same using [`Map.putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) and `forEach`  would be :

```
Function<Book, String> primaryKey = book -> book.getAsin() + "||" + book.getTitle();
Map<String, Book> booksByAsinAndTitle = new HashMap<>();
books.forEach(book -> booksByAsinAndTitle.putIfAbsent(primaryKey.apply(book), book));
```

***Note***: This ensures that the first `book` found against a key remains in the map.