# SortList<Employee> inside Map<String, List<Employee>> based on key

Tags: java

I have a `List<Employee>`

```
class Employee{
        String name;
        Integer id;
}
```

and my list looks like this

```
[{name:"Satya", id:123},{name:"Andrew", id:125}, {name:"Satya",id:124"}]
```

Now, I want to group the above list on names, for which I have written something of this sort.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> groupedData = data.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                                    LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
```

So, my result looks like this:

```
{"Satya":[{name:"Satya", id:124,cym:202012}, {name:"Satya", id:123, cym:202101}], "Andrew":[{name:"Andrew", id:125, cym:202012}]}
```

I want the list to be sorted, the end result should look something like this:

```
 {"Satya":[{name:"Satya", id:123, cym:202001}, {name:"Satya", id:124, cym:202101}], "Andrew":[{name:"Andrew", id:125, cym:202001}]}
```

As you can see all the records for every name are sorted based on cym.

Comment: Do you mean sorted *\*by name?\** Once you group, the list technically isn't sorted so you should be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by name, that will also group them, though the actual format is different than what you show.

```
Collections.sort( data, Employee::getName );
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the question, can you please give it a look

Answer (score 0):

You could sort before collecting, i.e. add `stream().sorted(...)`

```
data.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getId))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Is `collect()` and `groupingBy()` guaranteed to preserve existing order?  Actual question, I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @markspace According to this post the elements will be collected in encounterd order. [java-collectors-groupingby-is-list-ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172981/java-collectors-groupingby-is-list-ordered)